# Override the version of maven-surefire-plugin inherited from a Maven import

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

My project is driven by Maven, using POM not of my own making ([from Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/start/latest/project-base)). Apparently the POM file I see in my project depends on some kind of inheritance of other POM files. While I see no dependency for the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) in my own POM, this artifact is found in my project, as you can see on the right side of this screenshot from IntelliJ 2019.

[image]

I am no Maven maven, so I do not know precise details, but in nosing around I found some `import` lines, so I am guessing a Maven POM can dynamically inherit from other POMs.

The problem is that the version of `maven-surefire-plugin` present in my project is quite old, version 2.12.4. I am trying to run [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/), which [requires 2.22.0](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) or later. The [current version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) is `3.0.0-M3`.

Looking to the left end of that pink arrow, you can see that I added a `dependency` element in my POM.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
```

On that left arrow tip, I am asking for `3.0.0-M3` as an attempt to override the mysteriously imported/inherited specified version `2.12.4` seen on the right arrow tip. But my attempt failed, as the old version remained in place after doing a Maven `clean`, `install`. I even tried a restart of IntelliJ. But no go, my JUnit 5 tests still are ignored when running a Maven `test`.

➥ Is there some way to override the version of a dependency apparently inherited from some mysterious source?

Here is my POM, before trying that failed attempt at adding the `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>` dependency.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.basilbourque.acmeapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>acmeapp</artifactId>
    <name>AcmeApp</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!--<vaadin.version>11.0.1</vaadin.version>-->
        <!--<vaadin.version>12.0.0.beta1</vaadin.version>-->
        <vaadin.version>13.0.0.alpha3</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <!--<version>3.1.0</version>-->
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit 5-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.14.v20181114</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode can be activated with either property or profile -->
            <id>production-mode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: A plugin version is being overwritten by defining it in pluginManagement and never as a dependency....furthermore if you using JDK9+ you should use `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release> ` instead of target/source. Furthermore if you like to use Junit Jupiter this setup is also not correct...

Comment: @khmarbaise What is wrong with the Jupiter setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Specify `<plugin>`, not `<dependency>`

While I'm no Maven maven, the solution seems to be specifying `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>` in a `plugin` element rather than in a `dependency` element.

Delete your added `<dependency>`.

Look for the `<plugins>` (plural) section of your POM, containing one `<plugin` element for Jetty. Add this second `plugin` element:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
```

Then do a Maven `clean` and `install`. You should see the new version appear in the *Maven* panel in IntelliJ.

[image]

You can now execute a Maven `test` to see your JUnit 5 tests executed.

All of those plugins listed on the right of your screenshot can be updated, by overriding the imported POMs, if you feel the need.

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-deploy-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>

        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-install-plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-site-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: i had exactly the same issue. this works like a charm. thank you.